# Permissions For Deploying Database Schema Changes

Tags: database, deployment, scripting, permissions, updates

I've got a Python application that connected to Microsoft SQL Server 2000. The application checks for updates on startup and automatically applies them. Soon, it will need to handle database schema changes as well. Based on my research, it seems that creating a baseline script of my current database and then creating a new script for each schema change is the way to go. That way, any version of database can be updated to the newest version.

My question is how do I manage the permissions for these updates? Right now there's about 50 people using my application, most of which have read-only access. Ideally, I'd like any user to be able to perform the necessary changes such as creating or altering tables so that the first person to receive the new update will apply the new schema changes. If that doesn't happen, then he/she might not be able to use the application at all until someone with appropriate permissions updates the database.

I can see a problem occurring if every user can update the schema. What would prevent them from logging into the SQL Server Management Studio and causing issues like dropping tables, etc.?

Right now, this application is only deployed in once place, so it's easy for me to manage schema changes manually. But we do have plans to deploy to more areas and I'd for all this to be handled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You want to restrict users admin privileges, but at the same time you want them to perform admin activities... Bit of a "chicken and egg" problem :-)

## Option 1: Use webapp

Convert your program to run as a web application.

Bit drastic, however, much simpler maintanence. Your users no longer need to install Python, centralized upgrades and a shared connection pool to the database.

This solves your *database* authentication problem. Users authenticate themselves to the web application, not the database.

I use liquibase to manage my database schemas. It has a [servlet listener](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/servlet_listener) which can automatically upgrade the database when a new version of my app is deployed. (Liquibase also has a command-line interface for use by alternative technologies like Python).

## Option 2: encrypt admin password

You encrypt the admin password and make it available as a text file retrievable from a corporate web server, enabling any users application to download it at startup.

There is a security issue with this solution.... In order to decrypt the admin password, a shared secret needs to be built into your python application.... This is security by obscurity.